# cakephp 3 how to change the custom rule validation message in fly

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have created a custom rule, and i need to change the message on fly.

For example consider the following code. In this i need to show the appropriate message instead of rule message(Error Number) based on the constraints

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
           $validator->add(
                    'number_field',
                    [
                        'custom' => [
                            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                                if ($value < 10) {
                                    //need to change the error message as its less than 10
                                } else if ($value > 10 && $value <20) {
                                    //need change the error message its between 10 and 20
                                }
                                return true;
                            },
                            'message' => 'Error number'
                        ]
                    ]
                );
     return $validator;
}
```

Comment: I guess you can simply create two different rules for the same field with two different error messages

Answer (score 2):

Validation rule methods can return either a boolean that defines whether the validation succeeded, or a string which means that the validation failed, and that the string should be used as the error message instead of the one defined in the `message` option.

```
'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
    if ($value < 10) {
        return __('Error message for value < 10');
    } else if ($value > 10 && $value <20) {
        return __('Error message for value between 10 and 20');
    }

    return true;
},
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Validation\ValidationRule::process()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Validation.ValidationRule.html#_process)**

Answer (score 0):

```
   $validator
        ->add("number_field", "length", [
            "rule" => [ "minLength", 20],
            "message" =>__("{Your message}"),//Error message
            'on' => function ($context) {
                return !empty($context['data']['number_field']);
            }
        ])
```

When defining validation rules, you can use the on key to define when a validation rule should be applied.